# What is this 英語だと implying?

Tags: grammar

> 日本語と違って、英語だと文字だけじゃ区別もつきにくいし。
>
> Different from Japanese, you can easily tell the difference (gender) from just the letters/words (of names) in English.

I'm trying to understand why this is translated as "you can't necessarily tell gender through Japanese text like you can in English."

Note that it refers to gender by Japanese names.

But why にくい? Isn't this talking about English with 英語だと? Shouldn't it be やすい instead?

And also what is this つく? is it 吐く?

Comment: I have an answer for you, but first I would like to clarify that "it refers to gender by Japanese names" means that only Japanese names written in Japanese or English (i.e., ローマ字) are at issue. Is this right?

Comment: Isn't it "Different from Japanese, you can't easily tell the difference (gender) from just the letters/words (of names) in English."?

Comment: The names are Japanese and are written in kanji (or katakana). The speaker's name is a common Japanese name for males, but the speaker is actually a female. So she (speaker) was told that she was actually mistaken for a guy because of her name by a foreigner that can speak Japanese. She then proceeded to claim that she can sort of understand why the Foreigner mistook her for a he... This is where the phrase in question was used. With the Japanese and English translation, I don't quite get it. She seemed to imply that it's easier to know one's gender in English name, unlike Japanese. I think..

Comment: No. She doesn't imply that it's easier to know one's gender in English name, unlike Japanese. She says the opposite of what you think. She says that it's easier to know one's gender in Japanese (probably written in kanji), unlike English. For example, a name of 晶 is read Akira and it is a kanji used for girls' name, so people can guess the person who have a name 晶 is a girl, but they can't do it in the case of Akira.

Comment: I've finally got it. Btw, the certified English translation is "You can't necessarily tell the gender through Japanese text like you can in English". The "Different from Japanese..." Part is just a literal translation I made to match the certified translation. The reason I asked was because the meaning I got from the Japanese text and the translation seemed different. I didn't think the translation could be wrong, so I was convinced that I  had failed to understand this Japanese sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

日本語と違って、英語だと文字だけじゃ区別もつきにくいし。
This sentence says

> Unlike in Japanese, in English it is difficult to tell (gender) just from the characters (letters) used (in a name).

So the original translation was wrong. (Maybe they meant to say "can't?")
As an example, take the name Akira. A name used more for males than females, but there are plenty of examples of both. For males, it could be written 昭、昌、晃、彰、章、朗 and so on, but writing it like 晶 and あきら would probably make most people think the person is female. Obviously, this information is lost when written with the alphabet.

And, yes, it is talking about English with 英語だと, the problem was with the translation.

As far as 区別もつく goes, 付く would be the kanji for that, though it is usually written in hiragana.
[See here for usage frequency](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/N.02309/)

区別がつく= 209

区別が付く= 15

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot add comment, I just try and ask you here.
I am not sure what is the sentence before `日本語と違って`, I just best guess your whole sentence.

Is this sentence rightfully translated?
`Different from Japanese, you can easily tell the difference (gender) from just the letters/words (of names) in English.`

I think the part of にくい is misinterpreted in the English translation.
Because:

> 区別もつきにくいし
>
> > 区別がつく usage => add( and show) the difference
> >
> > 区別がつきにくい => difficult to add( and show) the difference
>
> Explanation of にくい
>
> > verb + にくい => adding "difficult" meaning to the action
> >
> > eg. 食べにくい => eg. (some form of food) **is difficult to eat** (using chopsticks)
>
> So I think the meaning is
>
> > Different from Japanese, it is still hard to tell/add the difference by just adding words/letters (if it is) in English.

update: `つく`は自動詞です my previous mistake makde it with を`つく`, please note.

Comment: `区別をつく 区別をつきにくい` <--「区別**が**つく」ですね。。「つく」は自動詞ですので・・・

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for pointing out, I have fixed it. Is there anything I have made mistake? Please feel free to let me know. Thanks again.